# Logical comparison returns false for two equal values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I'm trying to compare two _id in my MongoDB. I use logical operator `===` to compare them. Both values are the same but it's returning `false` and it's driving me nuts.

Anyone got a clue what might have gone wrong?

Thx

[image: Those to are the logged id's and false return value]

Comment: Where's the code? What sort of values are you talking about?

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the actual code.  `===` works just fine for two values that are actually the same so apparently you are either misusing something or your two values are not the same.  We could only help you if you showed the actual code and values.

Comment: 2882bdj3728ccc39===2882bdj3728ccc39 , these are MongoDB object id . Theoretically it should return true , but it's not .

Comment: Well the JavaScript environment isn't broken, so some assumption you're making is wrong. If the comparison returns `false` the values are not equal. **Post your code.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because *_id* has actually the type *ObjectId*. In order to compare two *ObjectId*s you should use instead the [equals method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals). Alternatively you can "cast" both to strings using the *toString* method.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

triple equals `===`  or (strict equals) performes a deep check of equality.

both operands must be of the exact type in order to `return true`, otherwise it will return false, no type coercion is applied.

If you're sure they're equals but it `return false` it means that probably you're unconsciously applying a type coercion.

Answer (score -1):

Ids have the same type of value ? String, integer etc... ?

Just try to compare your value and don't check the type like `==` operator